# Cell division and the Banach–Tarski paradox

Tags: physics, geometric-topology, biology

I would like to ask if there is a way to formalize the non-equilibrium process of [cell division](https://www.creativebiomart.net/researcharea-cell-division-proteins_406.htm) using notion/formalism/variation of Banach-Tarski paradox?

Somehow related work:

> 1. [The fractal globule as a model of chromatin architecture in the
>    cell](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10577-010-9177-0)
> 2. [Chromatin extrusion explains key features of loop and domain
>    formation in wild-type and engineered genomes](https://www.pnas.org/content/112/47/E6456.short)

[image]

Comment: The Banach-Tarski paradox says that we can convert one ball into two other balls *of the same size*. Cell division creates smaller cells (of half mass, for example). The Banach-Tarski paradox is really an explanation of why we need to assume a certain degree of regularity of a system in order to be able to make significant measurements. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2381519/58818 for a better explanation

Comment: The Banach-Tarski paradox decomposes a single ball into five "pieces" that are then reassembled into two new balls of the same size as the original. I put the word "pieces" in scare quotes because they are quite strange mathematical objects that don't have a well-defined volume. I think it would be hard to twist this into a description of cell division.

Comment: Also related: [What do you say to students who want to apply Banach-Tarski theorem in practice?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1351/75)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: It might be worthwhile to summarize that link as an answer here.